# How do I change my homepage category text's color?

Tags: html, github, jekyll

Here is my site's address below:
https://seongkyun.github.io/

and my GitHub address for the site is below:
https://github.com/seongkyun/seongkyun.github.io

My question is: How do I change 'others' color pink `#ec4c6a` to dark blue `#2d3e50`?

But I can't find the code line for that.
I thought that I changed color code pink `#ec4c6a` to dark blue `#2d3e50` exactly, but it is still having pink color `#ec4c6a`.

Only changed to dark blue `#2d3e50` after clicked twice (hide menu and un-hide).
I've cleaned my cache files on my web browser but still has the same problem.

Please help me, guys :)

Answer (score 2):

Your color got stamped with this css so you should change this line on your `main.css`:

```
.page h2, .tags-expo-section h2 {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    color: #ec4c6a;
}
```

into

```
.page h2, .tags-expo-section h2 {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    color: #2d3e50;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I've found that lines in `_scss/component/_page.scss`. And it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You color code is overwritten by other code, just try **!important**

```
color: #2d3e50 !important;
```

Answer (score 0):

if your external CSS is the problem to load simply you can use internal CSS style like

```
<h3 style="color:your color code;"></h3>
```